# Conditional distribution of $(X_i)_i$ given $\sum\limits_i X_i$ when $(X_i)_i$ is i.i.d.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables. Is there some way to determine the distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $S_n := X_1+\ldots+X_n$?

In the discrete case it is easy just using the definition of conditional expected value, but what about in the continuous case?

Comment: You could take the $n$-th root of the characteristic function of $S_n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't think that helps. Although the $X_i$ will be identically distributed given $S_n$, they will not be independent.

Comment: You could define $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$, $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$, define the event $A_x = \{X \leq x\}$, and then  $$ P[X \leq (x_1, ..., x_n)| Y=y] = \frac{f_{Y|A_x}(y|A_x)P[X_1\leq x_1]...P[X_n\leq x_n]}{f_Y(y)}$$ Then you can take partial derivatives with respect to $x_i$ if you like.  I think your $S_n$ morphed into my $Y$, although you could use the above in more general situations when $Y$ is not necessarily the sum.

Comment: When every $X_i$ has PDF $f$, their sum $$S=\sum_i X_i$$ has PDF $g=f^{\ast n}$ the convolution of $f$ with itself $n$ times, and the distribution of $X=(X_i)_i$ conditional on $S$ has conditional PDF $$f_{X\mid S}(x\mid s)=g(s)^{-1}\prod_i f(x_i)$$ with the notation $x=(x_i)_i$, on the set $$s=\sum_i x_i$$ Since your post also mentions "conditional expected value(s)", let me add that these are much simpler, since, for every $i$, $$E(X_i\mid S)=\frac1nS$$

Comment: @Did the part that is tripping me up is that the set $s=\sum_i x_i$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Presumably I should be able to calculate $P(X\in A|S=s) = \int_A f_{X|S}(x|s)\,dx$, but this just gives $0$ since the support of $f_{X|S}$ has measure zero. Should I be integrating with respect to a different measure? Also if you know of a reference that handles these subtleties carefully I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Did : You may want to qualify/modify your above comment since, as nulluser notes, in this situation that density would integrate to 0 (though it may work with some "impulse-like" integration).

Comment: @Michael No need to. The function $f_{X\mid S}(\ \mid s)$ in my comment is the density of the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $S=s$ with respect to the ($(n-1)$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure on the hyperplane of equation $x_1+\cdots+x_n=s$. Of course, the integral of any function whose support is a hyperplane, with respect to the ambient ($n$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure, is zero, but this (true) fact is rather unrelated to what I wrote.

Comment: @Did : Your qualification about using a different measure is the kind of thing I had in mind, it seemed an important thing to state.

Comment: @Did, in this case the $(n-1)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure seems to be the obvious choice of what to integrate with respect to, but how do we know? If instead of $S$ being the sum, for instance, if $S$ were the product of the $X_i$ or some other function, and the surface $\prod x_i = s$ is not just a plane, then how would I determine what measure to integrate with respect to? I'de be interested to have a reference that treats these more general conditional situations carefully if you could recommend one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my first comment...

#### General formula

Let $S$ be a random variable with PDF $f_S(s)$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $A$ be an event with $P[A>0]$. Then:
$$ P[A|S=s] = \frac{f_{S|A}(s|A)P[A]}{f_S(s)} $$ 
For intuition about this formula, it is easy to verify that for any interval $[a,b]$: 
\begin{align}
\int_{s=-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|S=s]f_S(s)ds &= P[A] \\
\int_{s \in [a,b]} P[A|S=s] f_S(s) &= P[A \cap \{ S \in [a,b]\}] 
\end{align}

#### Application to your problem

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d., let $S=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.  We want to find $P[(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq (x_1, ..., x_n) | S=s]$ for all relevant values of $s \in \mathbb{R}$.  For notational simplicity define $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$, $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$, $A_x = \{X\leq x\}$.  Note that:
$$P[A_x] = P[X\leq x] = P[X_1\leq x_1]\cdots P[X_n\leq x_n] $$
 Assume $S$ has PDF $f_S(s)$. We want to compute $P[A_x|S=s]$.  Applying the above formula gives: 
\begin{align*}
P[A_x | S=s] &= \frac{f_{S|A_x}(s|A_x)P[A_x]}{f_S(s)} \\
&= \frac{f_{S|A_x}(s|A_x)P[X_1\leq x_1]\cdots P[X_n\leq x_n]}{f_S(s)}
\end{align*} 
You can find $f_S(s)$ by $n$-fold convolution of the PDFs of $f_X(s)$ (assuming such exist).  You can find $f_{S|A_x}(s|A_x)$ by: 
\begin{align}
f_{S|A_x}(s|A_x) &= \frac{d}{ds} P[S \leq s| A_x] \\
&=  \frac{1}{P[A_x]}\frac{d}{ds}P[\{S\leq s \} \cap A_x]\\
&= \frac{\frac{d}{ds} P[X_1\leq x_1, ..., X_n \leq x_n, X_1+...+X_n\leq s]}{P[X_1\leq x_1]\cdots P[X_n\leq x_n]}
\end{align}

#### Computing probabilities with the conditional CDF

Notice that the above gives the *conditional cumulative distribution function*  (CDF) rather than the *conditional PDF*.  Conditional PDFs given  $X_1 + ... +X_n=s$ are hard to define since, as you note, this restricts $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ to a multidimensional set of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So real-valued functions defined over that measure-zero set would integrate to 0, not to 1. One would need to use PDFs with multidimensional impulses, which are tricky.  However, there is no need to use impulses:  Working with the conditional CDF gives all you need.

For example, suppose $n=2$ and let $B$ be the line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$ between the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.  How do we compute $P[(X_1, X_2) \in B | S=1]$?  We just observe:

$$P[(X_1, X_2) \in B | S=1] = P[\underbrace{X_1 \leq 1, X_2 \leq 1}_{A_{(1,1)}} | S=1] $$

A 2-d picture to illustrate the above equation would be great, but I do not know how to post a picture on stackexchange.